# Content-Disposition Has been blocked

Tags: file, batch-file, asp-classic, attachment, content-disposition

I have the following Classic ASP Code that worked yesterday flawlessly:

```vb
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="../../Connections/TDSC.asp" -->
<%
lp  = request("lp")
if lp = "" then
    lp = "c:\data\MyLibrary\"
end if
uid = request("uid")
Set oRs1_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
oRs1_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_TDSC_STRING
oRs1_cmd.CommandText = "EXEC usp_MakeMyLibraryBatch '"&lp&"','"&uid&"'"
oRs1_cmd.Prepared = true
Set oRs1 = oRs1_cmd.Execute
if not (oRs1.eof and oRs1.bof) then
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Response.CacheControl = "No-cache"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.bat"
    Response.write "md " & lp & chr(10)
    Response.Write(Replace(oRs1(0),"@@@",chr(10)))
    Response.End()
end if
%>
```

The query created a stream of text to the effect of

```
copy \\serverlocation\file.txt locallocation\otherFile.txt@@@
copy \\serverlocation\file.txt locallocation\otherFile.txt@@@
                            .
                            .
                            .
and so on...
```

This file would then be delivered to the browser with the name download.bat. The browser would prompt the user to open or download "download.bat". When they hit open it would run the batch file and copy all their files down from the server for their library.

Our network guys are super security freaks and probably did something to make this stop working from yesterday to today... Now it asks me "what do you want to do with "The url to the web page" ex: what do you want to do with makebatch.asp?lid=222, with the options save, saveas, and open. I can still saveas and rename it to download.bat and then run it but my users are not going to want to do that. And now to the question:

What could have been changed on the server to make it behave like this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking your network guys instead of us?

Comment: It's likely the `.bat` extension is being blocked by IIS as it's a security risk, maybe they've upgraded the IIS 6 to 7+?